# Is it possible to TDD when writing a test runner?

Tags: python, django, testing, tdd, bootstrapping

I am currently writing a new test runner for Django and I'd like to know if it's possible to TDD my test runner using my own test runner. Kinda like compiler bootstrapping where a compiler compiles itself.
Assuming it's possible, how can it be done?

Comment: Interesting idea, but the first version isn't bootstrapped. Later versions can be.

Comment: @PaulPhillips so I must write the first version using an existing testing framework and then rewrite it?

Comment: There might be some really clever and convoluted way to avoid that, but that's the only option I can think of. And it's a very practical approach.

Comment: @PaulPhillips Leave it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrapping is a cool technique, but it does have a circular-definition problem. How can you write tests with a framework that doesn't exist yet?

Bootstrapping compilers can get around this problem in several ways, but it's my understanding that usually the *first* implementation isn't bootstrapped. Later bootstraps would be rewrites that then use the original compiler to compile themselves.

So use an existing framework to write it the first time out. Then, once you have a stable release, you can re-write the tests using your own test-runner.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. One of the examples Kent Beck works through in his book "Test Driven Development: By Example" is a test runner.

Comment: Interesting. I will check it out.

Comment: If I remember well, Beck and Gamma even built the whole JUnit framework using TDD. You can find out more in this interesting interview : http://www.se-radio.net/2010/09/episode-167-the-history-of-junit-and-the-future-of-testing-with-kent-beck/